# GUI Development Framework for .Net?

Tags: .net, user-interface, design-patterns, frameworks

I'm searching for a framework to simplify the development of Winform graphic interfaces. I mean a framework with good implementation of GUI patterns (like MVC, Action, Undo, Observer, Container ...)

I'm tired of writing them every time just to find out that I forgot a little bit here and there!

Thanks.

Comment: You're describing WPF, am I missing the point?

Comment: Not exactly, WPF has MVC and two other I believe, Architectural patterns, Implements also action but that's almost it, Or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Mehran: OK so you want WPF + Prism, or something of that nature, but the crux of it is that WPF is the new hotness and has what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing to do is look at Codeplex.com for WinForms Frameworks. There you will find some such as:

Rocket Framework -Windows
http://rocketframework.codeplex.com/

Claymore MVP
http://claymore.codeplex.com/

koossery.MVCwin: an MVC open source framework for winform .NET applications
http://koosserymvcwin.codeplex.com/

and more...

Or as mentioned by others, you can switch to WPF which allows you to use patterns such as WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel MVVM  using Microsoft Frameworks such as Prism.
Here some info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

Comment: I can't find the link right now but there's a couple MVVM projects on there (a full version and a mini version).  Be cool to add them to your list @Carlos =)  Here is an [associated article on the subject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Comment: Done thanks Smudge202. I didn't include that because the question was about WinForms apps.

Comment: Part of my personal drive to push people away from WinForm into the WPF arena. ^^  +1